# Joomla display info after readmore

Tags: jquery, joomla

So I need to enter some information just after the readmore separator, the author of the post in this case. If I try to "hack" it with jquery, in the full post I can't find any readmore element. Is there any "joomla way" of doing this? I want to avoid to manually write the info in the editor, instead I want it to be dynamic. So for each post I want to render the author info just after the readmore element. Thank you

Comment: I can't understand even what you are asking or why you would use jquery. Just embed it in the layout underneath the place in the layout that embeds the readmore link (it's very explicit in the layout files, saying something like `echo JText::_('COM_CONTENT_READ_MORE');`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using meta tags in the article options and then I use jquery to render that info.